# I deleted the recovery partion for my Windows OS and now I cannot boot to Windows. Is there a solution other than a reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I was trying to create a dual boot for Windows and Ubuntu on my laptop, but I had too many particions and I could not get GRUB2 to work correctly, that is I could not boot to GRUB2. My computer came with Windows 7 and 2 drives a C: drive and a D: drive. Overtime I upgraded my system to Windows 8 and then to 8.1, when trying to install Ubuntu the live disk suggested that I would be creating a dual boot along with Windows 7 not 8.1.

I tried to install Ubuntu twice both times I could not boot to GRUB2 or get there through the BIOS interface. One YouTube video suggested that If I had four or more particions it would interfere with the intall process. I figured this was my problem because I had 6 partions to begin with (give or take one.) So, I moved eveything from my D: drive to my C: drive and then deleted the D: drive. I deleted the larger of the two recovery drives that were on the hard disk (the one that I thought pertained to the D: drive.) Now my computer won't boot to Windows. After I already could not reboot I installed Ubuntu manually, the live disk did not recognize any existing OS. The remaining partitions are as follows: 
[image: Partitions]

dev/sda3 is the particion where my C drive resides with all of my the system files and my pertinent data. My question is, **Is there any way to boot to Windows from this situation, or should I give up and reinstall windows 7 since I have the license for it, resulting in the loss of all of my software and data?**

Answer (score 1):

Please try to repair your boot grub by `live-ubuntu (ubuntu cd`)

```
>Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
>Choose "Try Ubuntu" 
>Connect Internet 
>Open a new Terminal, then type:
```

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update**

```
 >Press Enter.
  Then type:
```

**sudo apt-get install boot-repair**

```
After Installation Close the Terminal and Open Boot Repair ,
then Choose Recommended repair. It will repair automatically.
```

check the link http://bestthings4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-repair-boot-grub-in-ubuntu-1204.html

Comment: I will give this a try real quick, but boot-repair was useless the first two times I installed Ubuntu it could never resolve the issues. Nonetheless, I will give this a shot and report back.

Comment: This did not fix my problem, but it definitely did something I now have three ways to boot to windows, but none of them work. I will work with it some more tomorrow morning and document what happens in my orginal question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: if you are able to access data by live ubuntu then you can make backup of important data after that you can try other alternatives.